# Using gganimate with waffle charts

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, gganimate, waffle-chart

I've been playing with the `waffle` package, and am trying to get it to work with `gganimate`.

Using `mpg` as an example, I've created waffle charts to show number of models by each `class`. I would then like to use gganimate to display, in turn, a chart of models by class for each manufacturer. I can use `facet_wrap()` to show charts for all manufacturers at once, but would like to be able to cycle through them.

When I try to apply gganimate to a waffle plot, I get the error:

> Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
>    zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

I'm not sure if `waffle` is incompatible with `gganimate`, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(waffle)
library(gganimate)

data("mpg")
d <- mpg

d$class <- as.factor(d$class)
d$manufacturer <- as.factor(d$manufacturer)

plot <- d %>% count(manufacturer, class) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = class, values = n)) +
  geom_waffle(color = "white",
              size = .75,
              n_rows = 4) +
  ggthemes::scale_fill_tableau(name = NULL) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom")

#Facet wrap works fine:
plot + facet_wrap(~ manufacturer)

#gganimate returns error:
plot + transition_states(manufacturer, transition_length = 2, state_length = 2)
```

Would really appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the compatibility of `ggwaffle` with `gganimate`, but another option is to use the `animation` package to create a GIF. For example:

```
library(animation)

saveGIF({
  for (i in unique(d$manufacturer)) {

    d1 = d %>% filter(manufacturer==i)

    gg1 <- d1 %>%
      count(manufacturer, class) %>%
      ggplot(aes(fill = class, values = n)) +
        geom_waffle(color = "white",
                    size = .75,
                    n_rows = 4) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
        ggthemes::scale_fill_tableau(name = NULL) +
        coord_equal() +
        theme_minimal(base_size=40) +
        theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
              axis.text = element_blank(), 
              legend.position = "bottom",
              plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
        labs(title=i)
    print(gg1)
  }
}, movie.name="test.gif", ani.height=500, ani.width=500*3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response - using `animation` is definitely workable, although from looking briefly at the documentation it doesn't appear to offer the same control over transitions that `gganimate` does. But it's definitely an option if `waffle` and `gganimate` are incompatible!